# Markdown: referencing directories outside of a document's path ("peer" folders)

Tags: markdown

Hypothetical example:

My .md file is located at  c:/abc/123/docs

Inside that document, I want to have a link to c:/def/456.

How?  I have not found a way to reference anything other than my own path or those subordinate to it.  Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your Markdown file is at `c:/abc/123/docs` and you want to link to `c:/def/456`, then your relative link would be:

```
../../../def/456
```

Each `../` backs up one directory (to the parent). In this case, you are three directories deep (from root `c:/`), so you need to repeat `../` three times, then step down through the directories to get to your target.

You can test this out on the command line using the `cd` (change directory) command. From `c:/abc/123/docs` issue the command `cd ../` and you will now be at `c:/abc/123`. Issue the command again and you will be at `c:/abc/` and so on. Or just do the entire thing in one step (from `c:/abc/123/docs`): `cd ../../../def/456` and you should be at your desired target.