# Markdown files (names): is "index.md" - mandatory?

Tags: markdown, mkdocs

It's obviously popular at least, but MUST the "main" file in a mkdocs directory be called index.md?   What if I reference documents in a file folder that is elsewhere, ie not part of this file's heirarchy?  I ask as I'm having a slight issue with files linked that are elsewhere.  There is little if any documentation about this on the 'net that I have found.  Thx

Answer (score 4):

The file name "index.md" was chosen as it is how many (most) web servers are configured. Generally, URLs are in two forms (relevant to this discussion anyway). They either point to a directory or they point to a file.

- `/path/to/a/directory/`
- `/path/to/a/directory/with_a_file.html`

The commonly configured default behavior of a web server is that when it receives a request for a directory, it will serve the `index.html` file from that directory. In order words, when a request is made for `/path/to/a/directory/`, the server will return the file `/path/to/a/directory/index.html`.

Rather than reinvent this behavior with a different naming convention, MkDocs simply borrowed the same behavior. When you "build" your site using MkdDocs, the file at `/index.md` is built to `/index.html` and will be served by the server at `/`. Now, you could reconfigure a server to serve something different when a directory is requested, but the existing system has been in place for so many years now, that it would rarely make sense to do so.

So, if you are creating links within your documents to a page which is within a directory, link to that page directly: `/path/to/some/page.html`. However, if you are linking to the "main" page within a directory, link to the directory itself: `/path/to/a/directory/` and the page at `/path/to/a/directory/index.html` will be served.

The only additional consideration you need to be aware of is that MkDocs makes this even easier. You don't need to know what path the file will be built to. If you link to the Markdown file, MkDocs will do the "right thing" and rewrite the link to point to the built HTML file as [documented](http://www.mkdocs.org/user-guide/writing-your-docs/#linking-documents). So link to `some/page.md` and it will rewrite the link for you to `some/page.html` or `some/page/`, depending on how you have `use_directory_urls` setting configured. Note that when the `use_directory_urls` setting is `true` (the default), MkDocs used the "index" trick by putting each file in its own directory as an index file so no file extensions are ever used. However, as long as you use `.md` links internally, the links will be generated properly.

With a reread of you question, it occurs to me that perhaps you are trying to link to documents outside of the MkDocs site. However, it is not clear whether you mean documents hosted on the same site or hosted on other sites. So I'll cover both.

For documents hosted on other sites, simply include the entire address, including the host. Personally, I will often go to the page in my browser, and then select the address in the address bar and copy the entire thing into my document. For example, the link above to MkdDocs' documentation was `http://www.mkdocs.org/user-guide/writing-your-docs/#linking-documents` so I copied the entire thing into this answer as a link URL.

If you are asking about linking to other documents within the same host, then that depends on your configuration. For example, if you have multiple things served side-by-side where you have some documents at `http://example.com/foo/` which you want to link to from your MkDocs site which is served from `http://example.com/bar/` then you could use full links like you would do with external sites, or you could use relative URLs as explained in my answer to your question: [Markdown: referencing directories outside of a document's path (“peer” folders)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35513922/866026). Perhaps with a better understating of how the "index" pages work, you will be better able to construct relative links.

If, on the other hand, you are desiring to link to files which are outside of the document root, well you can't. Any web server I have seen is configured to raise an error as a security precaution and will not serve any files which are outside of the server root directory. If you want to serve a file and you can't remove it from its location outside of the server root, then you will either need to copy it, or create an OS level link to it in the file system. That said, depending on how your server is configured the OS level link may or may not succeed. However, that would be the subject of a different question.

Comment: I confess I didn't read all of that.......but it sounds like the answer is "no."  Right?

Comment: If you are talking about the situation addressed in the last paragraph, then yes, the answer is "no".